# multiple ruby version on my macOS will auto switch version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

pre: in my mac, I install rvm and rbenv both set a separate version.

and I look up "brew info ruby" is another version. in the terminal I use "ruby -v" is 2.3.7 is another version that I never set.

last time i use rvm to set default and current version to 2.5.3 it useful. then current that's wasn't work. how I to correct this issue...

- brew info ruby => 2.6.3
- rvm default and current 2.5.3
- rbenv global and local 2.5.3
- in terminal $ ruby -v 2.3.7 that's never set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose only one of them. You really can not have rbenv and rvm at same time. With rvm, it overrides the 'gem' command, so that would make rbenv useless.

Try this with rbenv:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then:

```
rbenv global 2.5.3
```